# Applying Homographies to Remove Perspective Distortion

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, homography

When calculating Homography, usually the information of the camera should be provided. Is there any straightforward technique to achieve perspective correction without actually having camera's properties? 
are there papers for that?

Answer (score 0):

A standard technique is calibration with a target.

To identify a (planar) homography, four points suffice. Take an image of the viewed plane where you place a contrasted rectangle and locate the corners in the image (pixel coordinates). You could do this by image processing or just manually. Then choose the pixel coordinates where you would like the corners to map after correction.

This will allow you to write a system of eight equations in the eight unknown parameters of the homography. Fortunately, this system is easily linearized and the solution is unique.

Comment: Hey Yves, I saw this tutorial. Is this exactly what you are referring?https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/  Do you know any paper about this method?

Comment: @programmer: looks like it. IMO, the method is too elementary to deserve a paper. Check the OpenCV documentation.

Comment: is there any deep learning-based or other methods? I do not want a basic method.

Comment: Calibration is a geometric problem, machine-learning is not suited at that. If you want to automate, look at interest point detectors/descriptors.